# how to make forking in asterisknow with FreePbx

Tags: asterisk

i have implement an asterisk now server (asterisk 1.6) with freePbx

and i make 3 extension "peers"

with number
200
201
202

and i each of them to x-lite account

i want when number 200 call number 201 also ringing at 202

in other word he ring 201 if he didnot answer , ring 202

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you want to cascade the dials given a certain timeout. Here is a potential solution with a 15s timeout between each dials.

```
exten => s,1,Answer() 
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/200,15,r) 
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/201,15,r) 
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/202,15,r) 
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

Before Hangup, you could also dispatch to the VoiceMail with something like

```
exten => s,n,VoiceMail(200@default)
```

More information about asterisk dial command can be found here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Ring Group or a Queue. You may have to install the modules from Module Admin.